# Streaming Video With DirectX C#

Tags: c#, .net, directx

I've created a program (C#) to play an audio/video file using DirectX library. Here's the code:

```
Video vid = new Video("K:\video_collection\vid1.avi");
vid.Owner = this;
vid.Play();
```

The codes works perfectly but what I actually wanted is how to play video over a web. At first, I think I just change the parameter for the constructor like this:

```
Video vid = new Video("http://localhost:88/server/vids/vid1.avi");
```

But, it cause the application crash. So how can I make it work? using another library maybe?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the FromUrl() method?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb324192.aspx